# Conditionally initialize an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c, if-statement, initialization

I want an array to have two different values, based on a condition. I can initialize the array inside the condition with the values i want.

```
if (myCondition == 0)
{
  byte my_message[8] = {0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B};
}
else if (myCondition == 1)
{
  byte my_message[8] = {0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10};
}
```

The problem with the previous approach is that the array has local scope, and it cannot be "seen" by the code beneath.

If I try to declare the array outside the condition with:

```
byte my_message[8];
```

then, inside the condition, I cannot use the previous way of initializing the whole array all at once.

There is no pattern in the data so I can use a `for` loop- inside the condition- in order to give value to each element of the array easily.

Is there a way of giving values to the array, besides the cumbersome:

```
if (myCondition == 0)
{
  my_message[0] = {0x00}; 
  my_message[1] = {0xAB};
  my_message[2] = {0xEE};
  ....
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector`

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one tag and delete the other. The answers for this question will be different for C and C++.

Comment: I'd use `memcpy`. A for loop is also reasonable.

Comment: For C, `byte my_message[8]; memcpy(my_message, myCondition ? (byte []) {0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10} : (byte []) {0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B}, sizeof my_message);`.

Comment: `memcpy` is not good because it will cost way more than the `my_message[8] = {0x00, 0xAB...`,

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu, "`memcpy` is not good because...". If you look at the assembler output of a fairly modern compiler, you will probably see the same code.

Comment: Write code that works first, then if it is a hotspot when you profile, worry about optimizing it.

Comment: You cannot do that directly in neither C nor C++ because one cannot use a **value** of an array. The value of the array is automatically transformed into a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `my_message` isn't changed, you could use a pointer instead of an array.

```c
const byte my_messages[2][8] = {
   { 0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B },
   { 0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10 },
};

const byte *my_message = my_messages[ myCondition ];
```

If you need to be able to change `my_array`, I'd use the following:

```c
const byte my_messages[2][8] = {
   { 0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B },
   { 0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10 },
};

byte my_message[8];
memcpy( my_message, my_messages[ myCondition ], sizeof( my_message ) );
```

You could memcpy from an anonymous array, but it's overly complicated and involves code repetition:

```c
byte my_message[8];
if ( myCondition ) {
   memcpy( my_message, ( byte[] ){ 0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10 }, sizeof( my_message) );
} else {
   memcpy( my_message, ( byte[] ){ 0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B }, sizeof( my_message) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first approach, but i had problem with the pointer later. Tried the second approach and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

In C you can use standard function `memcpy` and compound literals the following way

```
byte my_message[8];
if (myCondition == 0)
{
  memcpy( my_message, ( byte [] ){0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B}, 8 * sizeof( byte ));
}
else if (myCondition == 1)
{
  memcpy( my_message, ( byte[] ){0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10}, 8 * sizeof( byte ) );
}
```

In C++ it is better to use `std::array` instead of a raw array. For example

```
std::array<byte, 8>  my_message;
if (myCondition == 0)
{
  my_message = {0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B};
}
else if (myCondition == 1)
{
  my_message = {0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10};
}
```

Or if to use a raw array then if the compiler supports C++ 20 then you can use the range based for loop the following way

```
byte my_message[8];

if (myCondition == 0)
{
  for ( auto *p = my_message; auto item : {0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B} )
  {
      *p++ = item;
  }
}
else if (myCondition == 1)
{
  for ( auto *p = my_message; auto item : {0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10} )
  {
      *p++ = item;
  }
}
```

Otherwise if the compiler does not support C++ 20 then this declaration

```
auto *p = my_message;
```

must be moved outside the range based for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for this informative post. I tried the C version solution (arduino platform). However, I was getting an error that I could not understand: `taking address of temporary array`. I eventually solved it with another approach from another answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can wrap the message into the struct and use assign operator with compound literal.
2. You can use compound literal + `memcpy`

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef struct 
{
    byte my_message[8];
}message_t;

int foo(int myCondition)
{
    message_t my_message;
    if (myCondition == 0)
    {
        my_message = (message_t){0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B};
    }
    else if (myCondition == 1)
    {
        my_message = (message_t){0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10};
    }
    return 0;
}

int bar(int myCondition)
{
    byte my_message[8];
    if (myCondition == 0)
    {
        memcpy(my_message, (byte[]){0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B}, sizeof(my_message));
    }
    else if (myCondition == 1)
    {
        memcpy(my_message, (byte[]){0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10}, sizeof(my_message));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or you can `myCondition` as index:

```
int zoo(int myCondition)
{
    byte my_message[8];
    memcpy(my_message, 
          (byte[][8]){{0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B},
                      {0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10}}[myCondition], 
          sizeof(my_message));
    return 0;
}
```

`memcpy` way looks the most efficient:

https://godbolt.org/z/d6bMfejz5

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, this effect is achievable using a **reference** to an array in C++. I'm not sure how compliant this solution is but it compiles in pedantic mode for CLANG, GCC, ICC and MSVC.

```
int foo(bool cond) {
    byte arr0[8] = {0x00, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x0A, 0x0B};
    byte arr1[8] = {0x11, 0xA1, 0xBC, 0x71, 0x00, 0x02, 0x94, 0x10};
    byte (&tab)[8] = cond ? arr0 : arr1;
    return tab[0];
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/P6Th7bfcn

Answer (score 1):

Variadic template variant:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using byte = unsigned char;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)> make_array(Ts... ts) {
    
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)> { (T)ts... };
}

int main()
{
    bool myCondition = false;
    std::array<byte, 8> ary = myCondition 
        ? make_array<byte>(7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0) 
        : make_array<byte>(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

    for(auto it=ary.begin(); it != ary.end(); ++it)
    {
            std::cout << (int)*it << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why "design-in" a boolean limitation of only two conditions?

The following allows for what could be easily be less code in `main()`, and up to four conditions... (I've altered the values of the 4x8 bytes to bury an Easter Egg for those who are curious. Happy hunting...)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void show( byte *m ) { printf( "%.8s\n", m ); }

int main() {
    const byte my_messages[][8] = {
        { 0x41, 0x4C, 0x4c, 0x20, 0x47, 0x4F, 0x4F, 0x44 },
        { 0x48, 0x41, 0x54, 0x45, 0x4D, 0x41, 0x52, 0x53 },
        { 0x53, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x44, 0x48, 0x45, 0x4C, 0x50 },
        { 0x54, 0x4F, 0x4F, 0x20, 0x4C, 0x41, 0x54, 0x45 },
    };
    byte msg[8];

#   define FETCH( m, cond ) do { memcpy( m, my_messages[cond], sizeof m ); } while(0)

    FETCH( msg, 0 );    show( msg ); // prove

    FETCH( msg, 1 );    show( msg ); // prove

    FETCH( msg, 2 );    show( msg ); // prove

    FETCH( msg, 3 );    show( msg ); // prove

    return 0;
}
```